# Selenium C# Webdriver FindElements(By.LinkText) RegEx?

Tags: c#, regex, selenium, webdriver

Is it possible to find links on a webpage by searching their text using a pattern like `A-ZNN:NN:NN:NN`, where `N` is a single digit (0-9).

I've used Regex in PHP to turn text into links, so I was wondering if it's possible to use this sort of filter in Selenium with C# to find links that will all look the same, following a certain format.

I tried:

```
driver.FindElements(By.LinkText("[A-Z][0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}):([0-9]{2}")).ToList();
```

But this didn't work. Any advice?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

In a word, no, none of the `FindElement()` strategies support using regular expressions for finding elements. The simplest way to do this would be to use `FindElements()` to find all of the links on the page, and match their `.Text` property to your regular expression.

Note though that if clicking on the link navigates to a new page in the same browser window (i.e., does not open a new browser window when clicking on the link), you'll need to capture the exact text of all of the links you'd like to click on for later use. I mention this because if you try to hold onto the references to the elements found during your initial `FindElements()` call, they will be stale after you click on the first one. If this is your scenario, the code might look something like this:

```
// WARNING: Untested code written from memory. 
// Not guaranteed to be exactly correct.
List<string> matchingLinks = new List<string>();

// Assume "driver" is a valid IWebDriver.
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> links = driver.FindElements(By.TagName("a"));

// You could probably use LINQ to simplify this, but here is
// the foreach solution
foreach(IWebElement link in links)
{
    string text = link.Text;
    if (Regex.IsMatch("your Regex here", text))
    {
        matchingLinks.Add(text);
    }
}

foreach(string linkText in matchingLinks)
{
    IWebElement element = driver.FindElement(By.LinkText(linkText));
    element.Click();
    // do stuff on the page navigated to
    driver.Navigate().Back();
}
```

Comment: I love you! xD lol thanks a lot I will give this a shot tonight been messing around with this for 3 days now :)

Answer (score 2):

Dont use regex to parse Html.

Use [htmlagilitypack](http://htmlagilitypack.codeplex.com/)

You can follow these steps:

**Step1** Use `HTML PARSER` to extract all the links from the particular webpage and store it into a List.

```
HtmlWeb hw = new HtmlWeb();
 HtmlDocument doc = hw.Load(/* url */);
 foreach(HtmlNode link in doc.DocumentElement.SelectNodes("//a[@href]"))
 {
//collect all links here
 }
```

**Step2** Use this regex to match all the links in the list

```
.*?[A-Z]\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}:\d{2}.*?
```

**Step 3** You get your desired links.

Comment: Well I want to get there locations rather than just extracting them I can do the way you have said but mainly I want to get there locations and click them using Selenium. So if I want to use your method I should probably use Selenium webdriver to take the entirety of the HTML and find specific links text then use that to search for links using findelement but with the actual link text found previously. Your method sounds like its taking the long way around there must be a simpler method for Selenium.

Comment: @Sam i dnt know about Selenium so,cant comment on it

Comment: Thanks for your help I will see if I can find a Selenium specific solution, I have been searching for a few days now.