# Regular expressions and Selenium WebDriver xpath

Tags: regex, selenium, webdriver

How can I fix this code to work?

```
 public void check(WebDriver driver) {
    driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[matches(@href,'/staff/transcript/\\d{5}//.pdf')]")).click();
}
```

I must find a link where 5-digit indentifier varies.

Comment: no id? no fixed xpath? beat up these developers...

Comment: This question is substantially similar to [this one](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447690/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-findelementsby-linktext-regex/12451786). In this case, you would use `getAttribute("href")` instead of `getText()`, but the remaining code would be virtually identical.

Answer (score 1):

1. Try to get href attribute
2. parse that string to get that 5 digit identifier
3. use that identifier and construct your locator and click.

> ```
> String href=driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[contains(@href,'/staff/transcript/')][contains(@href,'.pdf')]")).getAttribute("href");
>
> String identifier=href.substring(href.lastIndexOf("/")+1,href.indexOf("."));
>
> driver.findElement(By.xpath("//a[matches(@href,'/staff/transcript/"+identifier+"//.pdf')]")).click();
> ```

Answer (score 0):

one possible solution to your problem: 
using js iterate through all  tags and find first which corresponds to your regex.

```
pubic String getLocatorByRegExp(){

 JavascriptExecutor js = (JavascriptExecutor) driver;
        StringBuilder stringBuilder = new StringBuilder();

stringBuilder.append("var regex = /^\d{5}$/");
stringBuilder.append("var x=document.getElementsByTagName('a');");
stringBuilder.append("for(var t = 0; t <x.length; t++){if(regex.test(parseInt(x[t].text()))) return x[t].text().toString();} ");

       String res= (String) js.executeScript(stringBuilder.toString());
       return res;
}
String properLinkText = getLocatorByRegExp();
driver.findElement(By.xpath(//a[contains(text(),properLinkText)])).click()
```

Quite complicated approach. But it seems to me that it is possible to find simplier solution.
Is it 5-digit indentifier unique  on the page ( i mean only one element on the page ?) 
If so, it is easy to find css locator or xpath to this element.
Provide please some piece of your html and point out element you need to click on.