# Compile Error Converting Output from FindElements to List of IWebElements

Tags: selenium-webdriver

I want to list the elements from part of a webpage. I am using the following statement to get the elements.

```
List<IWebElement> allElements = driver.FindElements(By.XPath("some path"));
```

But I’m getting the following compile error.
**Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.ObjectModel.ReadOnlyCollection' to 'System.Collections.Generic.List'**

Can someone help me out?

Answer (score 3):

use

```
ReadOnlyCollection<IWebElement> list = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(""));
```

More detaik: [Click](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12447690/selenium-c-sharp-webdriver-findelementsby-linktext-regex)

or

```
 IList<IWebElement> list = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(""));
```

Answer (score 2):

Its `IList<IWebElement> list = driver.FindElements(By.XPath(""));`
Where IList is taken from `System.Collections.Generic.IList<OpenQA.Selenium.IWebElement>`